# How to check Android EditText integer value?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an app that would calculate the income tax of a given person. There is an EditText field where the user must point out his monthly wage and then it's being calculated in the MainActivity.java. The problem is - when I try to do some maths using the given input field, an error `The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) EditText, double` shows up.

```
wage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wage);
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            wageAfterTax = wage * 0.25;
            result.setText("Your wage after tax deductions is " + wageAfterTax);
        }
    });
```

Can you please suggest what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wage` is a reference to an EditText object. You need to get the text from it and convert that to a number first.

```
wage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wage);
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String wageText = wage.getText().toString();
        double wageAmount = Double.valueOf(wageText);
        wageAfterTax = wageAmount * 0.25;
        result.setText("Your wage after tax deductions is " + wageAfterTax);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, almost. 'double' is not the best data type for handling money. I'd suggest BigDecimal instead, to avoid rounding errors.